# How to save updated data in a sqlite database?

Tags: sql, sqlite, system.data.sqlite

I am making a simple SQLite database. I am using [this Firefox addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager/) tool. I opened it, created a new database and import a .csv file. I can see all the data has successfully added. But when I remove the connection and opening that database again with that Firefox ad-don I can see that nothing has saved and it is a empty database. 
How to save data permanently to the sqlite database ?

Comment: How exactly did you create the database?

Comment: I opened the firefox addon and there is a "New Database" option in "Database" tab. I used that. Then import the .csv file to that.

Comment: And what database name did you enter?

Comment: "abc" then it automatically adds the extension and becomes "abc.sqlite"

Comment: And what directory name did you enter?

Comment: Just refered to my desktop